# Android: Does binding variable and passing to include tag layout work?

Tags: android, data-binding, include

I have a problem with databinding. In the documentation, it said we can use include tag to host a custom layout and passing binding variable to it. When I tryout on 4.1.2 phone and emulator, the data not seems to bind but only bind the main layout fields.

This is my code of the main layout:

```
<layout>

<data>
    <variable
        name="Job"
        type="nz.co.certifi.CERTIFI.Model.JobModel" />
</data>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:background="@color/TransparentColor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@color/TransparentColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            app:Job="@{Job}"
            android:id="@+id/layoutCertification"
            layout="@layout/view_certification_control"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

This is the layoutCertification:

```
<layout>
<data>
    <variable
        name="Job"
        type="nz.co.certifi.CERTIFI.Model.JobModel" />
    <variable
        name="Form"
        type="nz.co.certifi.CERTIFI.Model.FormROIModel" />
</data>
```

```
<nz.co.certifi.CERTIFI.Control.EditTextWithModel
    xmlns:sparkNS="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/nz.co.certifi.CERTIFI"
    sparkNS:modelProperty="CertificateId"
    sparkNS:modelType="JobModel"
    sparkNS:validationType="required_only"
    android:contentDescription="Job: Form Certificate Id"
    sparkNS:errorRequiredMessage="@string/error_reference_no_required"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/activity_roi_step_one_hint_reference_no"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@{Job == null? Form.certificateId : Job.certificateId}"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/txtReferenceNo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnReference"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnReference"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes it does. http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#includes

**Main layout**

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="plu"
        type="org.test.test.viewmodels.PluDetailViewModel" />
</data>
.
.
.
  <include
          layout="@layout/keypad_pludetail"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
          bind:plu="@{plu}"
                        />
```

**Included layout**

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="plu"
        type="org.test.test.viewmodels.PluDetailViewModel" />
</data>
.
.
.
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/keypad_accept"
                style="@style/KeyPadButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/keypad_accept"
                android:enabled="@{plu.isOK}"
                android:onClick="@{plu.confirm}"
              />
```

**In fragment**

```
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_plu_details, container, false);
    binding.setPlu(pluDetailViewModel);
    binding.executePendingBindings();
```

Comment: Evaluates the pending bindings, updating any Views that have expressions bound to modified variables.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html

Comment: Thanks I will try that out... when I used it on 4.4.2 and above , I don't need that statement and the view got the data.

Comment: I had couple scenarios when the data were null, mainly when I was using recyclerview. That's why I used that. Of course it's not necessary to use all the time.

Comment: I have tried the method and it works.. Why do we have to call separately and not integrated into the setPlu method.

Comment: Well, that's question for Yigit Boyar or George Mount, but if I should guess, it's all about reusability.

Comment: What is the way if we want to include this layout in more than one main layouts?

Comment: What XML namespace is "bind"?